# What do <: and :> mean when declaring a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, digraphs

I have stumbled across following lambda syntax, which I do not understand:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Callback>
void do_it(Callback callback) {
        callback();
}

template<typename T>
void p() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main() {
        auto a = <:&:> { };
        p<decltype(a)>();
        do_it(<:&:> { std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl; }); //this
}
```

Program above produces an output:

```
void p() [with T = main()::__lambda0]
Hello
```

Could you explain, what does `<:&:> {/* ... */}` mean? Is it possible to declare this way a lambda which takes an argument?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736282/what-is-this-smiley-with-beard-expression

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`<:` and `:>` are [digraphs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative). They get translated to `[` and `]` respectively. As such, your code is equivalent to:

```
auto a = [&] { };
do_it([&] { std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl; });
```

So it's just a lambda which captures everything by reference.

To declare a lambda which takes an argument like this, just add a parameter list after the capture group:

```
auto a = <:&:> (AType) { };
```

---

If you want whoever reads your code to hate you, you can use a mix of digraphs and trigraphs wherever possible:

```
auto a = <:&??)??<%>;
//       ^ same as [&]{}
```

Comment: It makes sense. It was really misleading because I don't understand who and why would use digraphs nowadays.

Comment: @aadam Yeah, where did you come across this code?

Comment: @aadam: I'm sure you've come up this code yourself , possibly because you're excited to share this with others :P

Comment: @TartanLlama In this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033142/c11-lambda-expressions-as-callback-functions

Comment: @Nawaz If I came up with this I would definitely post TartanLlama's example :)

Comment: Trigraphs (but not digraphs) are planned for removal in C++17, just in case you needed another reason not to use them.

Comment: @aadam digraphs exist, because the default character set and/or keyboard map in some locales does not have [] or {} characters.

Comment: @Elkvis are you aware of any character sets and/or keyboard maps that are in use nowadays and do not have [] or {} characters?

Comment: @aadam I'm not aware of any specifics, but that is the reason they were created.  I'm not sure if they're still even relevant, but not everyone uses the most up-to-date operating systems and software, so digraphs are still important to allow all developers to use the language.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, please note that the SO question referenced above has been edited (in the past few hours) to remove the digraphs in question.

Comment: How about `<:bitand:><%%>`?

Comment: *"If you want whoever reads your code to hate you"* ROFL! (or if I want to test whether my code reviewers are paying attention...)

Comment: @TobySpeight if you actually have reviewers who make you want to test them this way, then you have a serious problem in your team.